# Custom visual "Text Search Slicer" not working properly when modified to use exact match search. Power BI

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi, business-intelligence, powerbi-custom-visuals

In my Power BI report, I have downloaded the source code from the "Text Search Slicer" by DataBrothers which is avalible in the store from:

https://github.com/databrothers-code-storage/text-search-slicer

This search uses a "contains" search so I wanted to modify the code to use an "Is" search as I need exact match. I did the same thing with the regular "Text Filter" and it worked but I wanted to use this other custom slicer as it allows for sync slicers with other pages, something that the normal text filter does not.

The only thing I changed in the source code from the text search slicer is in the file "textSearchFilterService.ts" in \src\services on line 20 the operator from "Contains" to "Is". Also the the GUID in the pbiviz.json so it is detected as a new visual.

It perfoms the search correctly applying exact match but the thing is that when I apply the filter (meaning I perfom a search that is not blank) and then I change to another page and go back to the page where the visual is, the search bar has dissappeared and the visual is completely white. The weird thing is that to get it to work again you either delete and put the visual back or right click in the visual,  go into "view as table" and then go back and the search bar is again visible and working fine.

I looked into the code but cannot manage to get around that issue, I was wondering if someone might know the solution.

Thanks a lot to everyone.